# WSO2 AD LDAP broke after creating new wso2carbon.jks keystore when installing new cert

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Created new keystore when I was installing a new cert. The public cert is working ok, but ldap seems to have broken after I created the new keystore. If I restore the old keystore (wso2carbon.jks), it ldap works fine. Any idea what I'm missing?

Update 2020/10/6

Apparently the issue was with the password I had put in for ldaps. I went back into the user store and updated the password (it should have been right as nothing had changed) and that did the trick. I also had an issue with the AD cert for the userstore being out of date when I reverted back to an older snapshot and didn't realize it. So I also added the new public cert from the DC to the client-trust.jks keystore. Also I had recreated the wso2carbon.jks keystore from a new set of certs I got using the private/public certs I acquired. Seems to be working fine now. I think there was some weird bug in WSO2 that was showing it connecting to LDAP despite the password being wrong in the userstore after I had updated the cert. Not really sure what else it could have been, because if the password had been wrong, it should not have ever connected in the first place, but did. Really weird.

Comment: Believe you are using LDAPS instead of LDAP for your AD connection. This requires WSO2 client-trustore.jks file to contains the public certificate of the AD server. When you change the `wso2carbon.jks`, have you changed the `client-trustore.jks` as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ldaps for better security. I didn't modify my client-truststore.jks as it already had the public certificate for my AD server. Only thing I did was recreate the wso2carbon.jks using a new private key and public key. 

As I said previously, reverting back to the old keystore (wso2carbon.jks) fixes the ldaps issue, but I didn't alter or modify the client-truststore.jks in any way before or after creating the new wso2carbon.jks. Do I need to add anything to the client-truststore.jks after creating a new wso2carbon.jks?